# How I can select rows from a dataframe with a specific columns value?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, helper

I have one dataframe (peak.anno_C1_4) with 5578 obs and 19 variables and a list of value (intestine_unique) that I want to check if they are in one of the dataframe's columns, and if they are in, I want to extract the corresponding rows in a new dataframe (with all the 19 variable)

```
intestine_unique <- c("atm-1", "cdc-3", "fgf-5")

peak.anno_C1_4 

chr  start    end       name
1    12345   12347     atm-1
1    2345    2344      cdc-3
2    3456    3455      fgf-5
2    4567    4566      dfr-3
```

I want only the first three rows so I do this loop but it doesn't work

```
intestine<-data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(intestine_unique)){
  for (j in 1:length(peak.anno_C1_4$SYMBOL)){
    if (i == j)
      intestine <- peak.anno_C1_4
  }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

I can envision this a couple of ways. If you are looking for any full string matches, you can use `if_any` and `%in%`. Alternatively, you might be looking for partial string matches, in which case I would use `grepl`. Note the differences in outputs for the full an partial string matches. I use the `starwars` dataset here as an example.

```r
library(tidyverse)

vals <- c("red", "Watto")

data <- starwars |>
  select(name, hair_color, skin_color, eye_color)

#full string mataches
data |>
  filter(if_any(everything(), \(x) x %in% vals))
#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#>   name        hair_color skin_color    eye_color
#>   <chr>       <chr>      <chr>         <chr>    
#> 1 R2-D2       <NA>       white, blue   red      
#> 2 R5-D4       <NA>       white, red    red      
#> 3 IG-88       none       metal         red      
#> 4 Bossk       none       green         red      
#> 5 Nute Gunray none       mottled green red      
#> 6 Watto       black      blue, grey    yellow   
#> 7 Darth Maul  none       red           yellow

#partial string matches
data |>
  filter(if_any(everything(), \(x) grepl(paste(vals, collapse = "|"), x)))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>    name        hair_color skin_color       eye_color
#>    <chr>       <chr>      <chr>            <chr>    
#>  1 R2-D2       <NA>       white, blue      red      
#>  2 R5-D4       <NA>       white, red       red      
#>  3 IG-88       none       metal            red      
#>  4 Bossk       none       green            red      
#>  5 Nute Gunray none       mottled green    red      
#>  6 Watto       black      blue, grey       yellow   
#>  7 Sebulba     none       grey, red        orange   
#>  8 Darth Maul  none       red              yellow   
#>  9 R4-P17      none       silver, red      red, blue
#> 10 Shaak Ti    none       red, blue, white black
```

Comment: Thank you, I use the first option that you suggest me but I have this error

```
Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing ..1 = peak.anno_C1_4$SYMBOL == intestine_unique.
x Input `..1` must be of size 5587 or 1, not size 2265.
Backtrace:
 1. peak.anno_C1_4 %>% ...```

Comment: what is the exact line of code that you wrote?

Comment: peak.anno_C1_4 |> filter(peak.anno_C1_4$SYMBOL == intestine_unique)

Comment: That is not the code I wrote in my answer...

Comment: try `peak.anno_C1_4 |> filter(if_any(everything(), \(x) x %in% intestine_unique))`

Comment: or `peak.anno_C1_4 |> filter(if_any(SYMBOL , \(x) x %in% intestine_unique))`

Comment: With this two codes I have an empty dataframe with 0 rows, that's why I try the other code but I'm sure that there is a correspondence

Comment: This code works with the example you posted. are you using `dplyr::filter`?

Comment: Yes
``` 
inte <- peak.anno_C1_4 %>% dplyr:: filter(peak.anno_C1_4$SYMBOL %in%  intestine_unique)
>0 rows | 1-10 of 19 columns

` ` ` 

I have this result

Comment: `peak.anno_C1_4 %>% dplyr::filter(SYMBOL %in% intestine_unique) `